# Permanent instances with GCE Autoscaling and load balancers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, autoscaling

Is there any options in Google cloud autoscaler for marking some number of instances as permanent which shouldn't be destroyed by autoscaler?

In my use case, I need to run some instances all the time (which also serve the critical data) and only scale up/down when traffic load increases/decreases.

Answer (score 0):

No, the managed instance group will not mark any of the instances as permanent. Instead, create 2 instance groups, one with auto-scaling and one without. When you create your backend service, you can select both instance groups as the backends.

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for the response. I have now two instance groups as you suggested but apparently now load-balancer doesn't allow to server same traffic for two different instance-group in backend because of conflict with same path pattern. Any help?

Comment: Hi Slal, make sure to use a single Backend Service that includes both your instance groups.

Comment: Thanks Patrick!!! Didn't notice that.